# Mysql how to select data order by number of occurences

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for the query to get the top 10 presence on a table.
My table:

```
id | art_id | tag_id
```

I want to have the top 10 of the most called tag_id (example: 150 tag_id "25", then 146 tag_id "36", then 132 tag_id "76" .....)
I don't really know how to get that... And at the end, join to have the name of the tag from an other table:

```
tag_id | tag_name
```

Any idea please?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
   m.tag_id, o.tag_name, COUNT(m.tag_id) FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN
    myothertable o ON o.tag_id = m.tag_id
GROUP BY 
   m.tag_id 
ORDER BY 
   COUNT(m.tag_id) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Ok, found a good query based on yours! `SELECT s.tag_id, COUNT( s.tag_id ), t.tag
      FROM stories_tags s
      join tags t on t.id = s.tag_id
      GROUP BY s.tag_id
      ORDER BY COUNT( s.tag_id ) DESC 
      LIMIT 10`

Comment: @user2670167 Oh, those are two tables? Try that instead - using the correct table names, obviously.